# Maintaining a ratio of two liquids in a water bottle while someone sips at a variable rate

Tags: control-engineering, adaptive-control

I had an idea for a fun project.

I want to control blood alcohol content (BAC) throughout an evening. A target BAC can be set for several points during the night. This curve is constrained by the bodies ability to metabolise alcohol over time.

This target BAC "curve" can also be adjusted at any point throughout the night. Of course, this is also constrained by the ability for the body to metabolise the alcohol already present in the system.

You would drink from a drink bottle containing an alcoholic liquid and a non-acoholic liquid. You could sip from the drink bottle at any rate you like. The size-of and duration-between each sip would be variable.

The bottle has a single chamber, which flavored liquid can be dosed into, of a fixed amount, at any time via bluetooth from a smart phone. The flavored liquid would be replaced by an alcoholic drink (possibly diluted if necessary).

There would also be an app that would tell the user to drink from the bottle if they are not drinking enough to maintain a BAC.

The single chamber drink bottle design is fixed - even though there may be better options such as using three chambers (mixed, alcohol, non-alcoholic), or just-in-time mixing like a soda machine, or continuous instead of fixed sized dosing.

**How to design the system and algorithm to fit to this curve given the constraints of the system?**

The topic area seems to be called "ratio control" or "adaptive control".

The biggest challenge is the uncertainty of the sipping behaviour. The user notification system is necessary because if the user doesn't drink at all, there is no way to increase the BAC. Also, there is always the possibility that the user chugs the whole drink in one go. If we dose assuming small sips, then we have to be careful of this possibility.

Comment: People metabolize alcohol at different rates - will you assume a constant or measure it?

Comment: It will be a rough estimate based on body weight and sex.

Comment: very interesting project ... what is your specific question? ... your present question is too broad

Comment: Looking for whether this is similar to an existing problem in control engineering that has a specific algorithm to use.

Comment: somewhat similar to a liquid fueled rocket engine

Comment: Professional grade, DOT / NHTSA Certified, [instruments](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u8Dg9.png) are available for U$100, and there are lots of free software-only Android APPs; **how** is your idea "better", and why we would prefer it over the competition?

Comment: @Rob First, it's a fun project, not business idea :). It's better because you don't have to think or remember to do anything. You don't have to change your behavior. Who is going to take a breathalyzer to a party and remember to do it every 30mins for example...

Comment: OK, thanks for the clarification; it may help to add the purpose to your question. I'll give you +1 for the use of the word "chugs".